# Rails 3 - Need shared model methods for polymorphic models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, shared-libraries, polymorphic-associations

Currently I have repeated code in multiple modules something like this:

```
def do_something_polymorphic
  self.something_polymorphic_able.where(.....).each do |thing|
    ...
  end
end
```

In the spirit of DRY, I tried moving `do_something_polymorphic()` into a module at `/lib/shared_methods.rb`.  When I added `include SharedMethods` in my models I got an error:

```
uninitialized constant Chapter::SharedMethods (NameError)
```

Which I could not figure out how to get around.

Then I tried loading the module file into the models (`load 'shared_methods.rb'`).  It loaded OK, but the Module construct threw off the namespace and `do_something_polymorphic()` was undefined for the model in which it was loaded/included.  So "Module" appears not to be an option if you are trying to self-reference an object.

Lastly, I removed the module construct from the shared_methods.rb file and just left the do_something_polymorphic() method alone in the file.  It loaded OK, but when I ran the method I got the error:

```
NoMethodError: private method `do_something_polymorphic' called for #<Polymorphic_Object:0x007fc27e5b8338>
```

Not sure where to go from here.  I could go back to setting this up as a module and try to pass "self" in as an object parameter to the method, but I would like to preserve the ability to cleanly call the method against its object:  `current_object.do_something_polymorphic`

Short of going the inheritance route (which I really want to avoid,) is there a way to share, across multiple models, a method that uses the `self` keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include lib/ modules automatically by modifying the application configuration.

```
#config/application.rb

config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Comment: Thanks @Salil.  That fixed the "include SharedMethods" issue.  Which in turn, fixed the other issue. I'm now able to call the do_something_polymorphic() method from all the different object types.  This makes everything nice and DRY!  Thanks again.